# What are the essential layers, a well structured Spring MVC project should have?

Tags: spring-mvc, model-view-controller, dao

I follow some of the tutorials where i found that the following layers,   **Repository layer, Model layer and Service layer** are the basic layers. But i am confused about **Business layer, DAO layer and Manager layer**.

Comment: This is a highly opinionated question. See also my answer [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/258196/java-application-structure-horizontal-vs-vertical-split/258197#258197).

Comment: Yes I agree @M.Deinum. I use three basic layers Dao, Manager and Service. It is my opinion about the spring MVC. I want to know more opinions about this concern.

Answer (score 1):

Spring MVC is front end architecture and we have to have the layered architecture to separate the logic.

I have created layers by separating the concerns.

1. Controller layer (com.app.spring.contoller)
2. Service layer (com.app.spring.service)
3. Data Access layer (com.app.spring.dao)
4. Persistance layer (com.app.spring.model)

[click here to learn more](https://malalanayake.wordpress.com/2014/07/27/spring-mvc-with-spring-hibernate/) !

Comment: Thanks vikas. i follow the tutorial and understood the logic behind

Comment: How to package and structure your application is a highly opinionated topic. See also my answer [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/258196/java-application-structure-horizontal-vs-vertical-split/258197#258197). There is no right or wrong way there are multiple ways.